# How to create search form in MERN Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

My search form isn't working for some reason. If I type something in the search it returns me all products again. I need some help.

Here is my form:

```
<form className="product--SearchForm" onSubmit={searchProduct}>
                            <input type="text" className="product--Search" name="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
                            <input type="submit" value="search"/>
                        </form>
```

Here is my request:

```
const searchProduct = () => {
        fetch (`${API}/products`, {
            method: 'GET',
        })
        .then (response => response.json ())
        .then (response => {
            console.log(response)
            setProducts(response)
        })
        .catch (error => {
            console.error (error);
        });
    }
```

Here is the controller in backend:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    productService.getAll(req.query).then(products =>{
        res.status(200).json(products)
    }).catch(() => res.status(500).end())
})
```

And the service:

```
async function getAll(query) {
    let products = await Product.find({}).lean()

    if (query.search) {
        products = products.filter(x => x.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.search))
    }

    return products;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you aren't adding a query to your url... Try `${API}/products?search= YOUR SEARCH VALUE `.

Comment: Thanks man ! I have one more question. Why this reload the page ? I don't want that, because I have useEffect request that is running with the same request but for all products. And I see that the query has .search, it seams that I can't see the result becaouse of the reloading.

Comment: That's the default behavior when submitting a form, you should prevent that in your searchProduct method... const searchProduct = (e) => { e.preventDefault(); ....}

Comment: Thank you so mush!